# Jquery keydown() with number format not work correctly on android webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, webview

I have encountered a strange behavior on android browser / webview. I was testing an input that will automatically format to phone number format "(xxx) xxx-xxxx". But then what happened was when I tapped or press any number on androids keyboard, the first input was like this "(x" but then the cursor was in between "(" and "x". Is there a way to put the cursor after "x" value?

I tested this on iPhone and windows web browsers and it works fine. Please let me know if there are mistakes on my jquery or javascripts.

Thanks

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>Sample Phone Number Format</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="phone" /> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#phone').on('keydown', function (event) {

                objval = $(this).val();
                if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {} else {
                    if (!((event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58) || (event.keyCode > 95 && event.keyCode < 106) || (objval.length > 13))) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    } else {
                        if (objval.length == 0) {
                            $(this).val(objval + '(');
                            alert(objval + '(');
                        } else if (objval.length == 4) {
                            $(this).val(objval + ') ');
                            alert(objval + ') ');
                        } else if (objval.length == 9) {
                            $(this).val(objval + '-');
                            alert(objval + '-');
                        } else if (objval.length >= 14) {
                            if (event.keyCode == 9) {
                                return;
                            } else {
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#phone').on('keydown', function (event) {

                var objVal = $(this).val();
                if(objVal.length < 14)
                {
                    validateCallerForm(objVal + String.fromCharCode((96 <= event.keyCode && event.keyCode <= 105)? event.keyCode-48 : event.keyCode));
                }
            });

            //Validates proper phone format, true if valid phone number, false otherwise
            function isValidPhoneNumber(elementValue) {
                var numberPattern = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
                return numberPattern.test(elementValue);
            }

            //validates entire caller form, also updates css classes for proper response
            function validateCallerForm(PhoneNumber) {

                if (isValidPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber)) {
                    alert("true");
                } else {
                    alert("false");
                }

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Giving +50 Bounty to who'm will answer this correctly

Comment: Have you considered applying that formatting on `blur` instead of `keydown`? As a user I find it annoying to have what I'm typing reformatted as I go (even when it works).

Comment: no, because what they want was to reformat the numbers while typing. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite the code on my #phone keydown event and this will work on iPhone, Android, webkit browsers.

```
$('#phone').on('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) {
        // ignore if BKSPCE, left arrow, or right arrow
    } else {
        // validate if anything else
        inputval = $(this).val();
        var string = inputval.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
        var first3 = string.substring(0,3);
        var next3 = string.substring(3,6);
        var next4 = string.substring(6,10);
        var string = ("(" + first3 + ") " + next3 + "-" + next4);
        $(this).val(string);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think that is better to explain why first code not working and why this rewrite version can.

Answer (score 0):

you have to first define listener for typing and copy-paste like below (not required) :

```
$("#phone").keyup( function() {
    maskLine(this);
});
$("#phone").change( function() {
    maskLine(this);
});
```

Then, to manage cursor placement, you have to cache previous phone number and then, you could compare difference and update cursor position if needed.
So declare, you have to declare a global array like this :

```
var _cacheElementValues = new Array();
```

At last, you can check the function below, it applies your mask to phone number field and manage cursor placement :

```
function maskLine( element ) {
    element = $(element);
    var maskedLine = '';
    var line = element.attr('value');

    // check the cache of the input and abord if no change since last treatment
    if (_cacheElementValues[element.attr('id')] != undefined && _cacheElementValues[element.attr('id')] == line) {
        return;
    }
    line = line.replace(/\D/g, ''); // remove all characters != digits
    line = line.substring(0, 10);
    if (line != '') {
        // apply mask
        if (line.length <= 2 ) {
            maskedLine = "(" + line;
        } else if (line.length < 6) {
            maskedLine = line.replace(/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{0,3})/g, '($1) $2');
        } else {
            // mask : '(XXX) XXX-XXXX'
            maskedLine = line.replace(/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{0,4})/g, '($1) $2-$3');
        }        
    }

    // define cursor position at the end of the input by default
    var pos = maskedLine.length;

    // Change cursor placement if necessary
    if (typeof element[0].selectionStart != 'undefined') {
        var start = element[0].selectionStart;
        var end   = element[0].selectionEnd;
        var insText = element[0].value.substring(start, end);

        // get current cursor placement
        if (insText.length == 0) {
            pos = start;
        } else {
            pos = start + insText.length;
        }

        // find how many digits typing since last mask application
        var previousLength = 0;
        if (_cacheElementValues[element.attr('id')] != undefined) {
            previousLength = _cacheElementValues[element.attr('id')].replace(/\s/g, '').length;
        }
        var diff = maskedLine.replace(/\s/g, '').length - previousLength;

        // if sum of new typing digit is > 0 : we change cursor placement
        if (diff > 0) {
            pos += (diff - 1) + Math.round((diff-1)/3);
            if (pos%6 == 0 && maskedLine.length >= pos+1) pos++;
        }
    }

    // update input data & cache
    element.val(maskedLine);
    _cacheElementValues[element.attr('id')] = maskedLine;

    // update cursor placement
    element[0].selectionStart = element[0].selectionEnd = pos;    
}
```

You can find this example on jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UE9LB/5/

I hope this little explantion can solve your problem ;)
Enjoy !

ps: i apologize for my poor english :s

Comment: Thank you for answering but It does not work on andriod very well. I tried to input the first digit "9" and it renders "(9" but then the cursor was in the middle of "(" and "9".

Comment: @JeffRobertDagala Did you try to log the cursor detected position ? to know why the position is'nt good. Perhaps, it's not the detection of the position but the update of the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend at least starting with an existing plugin rather than going through your own isolated rounds of solving issues.

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Comment: Thank you for answering, I tried the said plugins but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to set the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties of the input element.  After you format the value, set these properties to `this.value.length`.

```
this.selectionStart = this.value.length;
this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
```

But, where you are going to run into trouble is when the cursor is not at the end of the text.  Eg, the user has manually positioned the cursor to a position within the text.  To prevent the cursor from jumping to the end, you will need to detect the cursor position before you format the input, then put the cursor back in the appropriate position after formatting.

**Edit:** [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkDPr/6/) may get you started, but isn't perfect yet.